# Codelens Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, codelens

How does one get around having codelens on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

On one of my devices I have it working on Visual Studio 2015 CE (I have no idea how I got it on that installation). Yesterday, I installed Visual Studio 2015 on another device but no codelens. I have SSDT and SSMS 2016 installed (as suggested on another post) but still no codelens.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx CodeLens is strictly a non-Community-edition feature. You should expect any workaround to be disabled by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Install SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) and do not forget to set checkboxes for SQL Server Analysis, Reporting and Integration.

Borrowed here: [install-codelens-visual-studio-community-2015](http://instinctcoder.com/install-codelens-visual-studio-community-2015/)

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work as referenced in the question.  Can you confirm if it still works now? I will also try it again when I get home

Comment: I just downloaded and installed SQL Server with developer license (no 10GB data cap,  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads ) and noticed new features in VS. I actually had to google what Codelens is...

Comment: Okay. I will try it out tonight!

Comment: I can confirm that this didn't work for me. I guess @Lex Li was right with his comment